# Shape puzzle, find the final sequesnce or word?

Tags: logical-deduction, word, pattern

[image: Shapes]

Clues:
The only instructions given to solve this is that the answer can be alpha-numeric text.

Ideas:
So far I have this:

- SQUARE: 101111
- DIAMOND: 2111112
- RECTANGLE: 111211021
- HEXAGON: ?1?1011

Though I can't see a recurring pattern to extrapolate what H and X would be, or if there's an entirely different logic mechanism in this puzzle.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Puzzling :) Please can you supply a source for this question? All puzzles posted from elsewhere (e.g. puzzle books, newspapers, webpages, IQ tests, interview materials, etc.) need to have their original source mentioned in the post, so that credit can be given to the original creator(s). You can just edit the question to add a line explaining where you found it. (Same goes for your other question posted today too...) Thanks!

Comment: The vowels are 1

Comment: @Stiv Hey! Understood, I've got a reddit link for the anagram puzzle (editing now), though this one's from a series of mini-puzzles being shared in a private telegram group. Do I mention that in the description aswell?

Comment: @nomad.lw Any information you can provide is generally useful. If you know where the series of mini-puzzles is from before the telegram group, that's best - e.g. is this a group of users trying to collaboratively crack puzzles from a competition, or sharing posts together from a particular website, or just creating puzzles yourselves for each other to crack...

Comment: @Stiv Gotcha, will be verbose as much as possible. Will post more, thanks for having me!